# Find the letters with the longest streak in a string

Tags: python

Given a string of lowercase letters, find the length of the longest streak and the alphabetical letters with the longest streak.

### Output Format

For each test case, output the length of the longest streak and the letters with the longest streak, separated by space. In the case of ties, output the tied letters in lexicographical order.

| Sample Input | Sample Output |
| --- | --- |
| bacacccbba | 3 c |
| ccbccbb | 2 bc |
| cba | 1 abc |
| c | 1 c |

### Explanation

- For **bacacccbba**, the longest streak is `ccc` with a streak length of `3` and alphabet c. The output is `3 c`.
- For **ccbccbb**, the longest streaks are `cc`, `cc`, and `bb` with a streak length of 2. The output is `2 bc`.

### Constraints

1 ≤ `t` ≤ 10000

1 ≤ `n` ≤ 10000

The alphabet set of the string is `a-z`.

### What I have tried

I have the following code, which gives the output of a single streak. I need to have the tied function as well.

```py
def longest(seq):
    max_count = 0
    max_char = ""
    prev_char = ""
    
    for current in seq:
        if prev_char == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count
            max_char = current
        prev_char = current
    print(max_char,max_count)

longest()
```

So what will be the procedure?

Comment: The first part of the procedure will be to decide which programming language you will use to solve this coding puzzle. The second step is to take a [tour] of Stackoverflow, read the [help], learn [ask] questions, and review what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: You can't just track the max.  If a streak EQUALS the current `max_count`, you have to add that to the winning alphabet.  If a streak BREAKS the current `max_count`, then you start with a new alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

I track the current streak.  When the streak ends, if it equals the current longest, then we just add it to the alphabet.  Otherwise, we start a new alphabet.  Notice that I add a marker so we handle the final character.

```
def longest(seq):
    seq += '@'
    alphabet = []
    count = 0
    max_count = 0
    prev_char = ''
    for current in seq:
        if prev_char == current:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count == max_count:
                if prev_char not in alphabet:
                    alphabet.append(prev_char)
            elif count > max_count:
                max_count = count
                alphabet = [prev_char]
            count = 1
            prev_char = current
    print(max_count,''.join(sorted(alphabet)))

longest("bacacccbba")
longest("ccbccbb")
longest("abc")
longest("c")
```

Output:

```
3 c
2 bc
1 abc
1 c
```

Comment: as it's checking the last character too after finding the `max_count`, is it affecting the time complexity(if it may be a big set of characters)?

Comment: Adding one char to a string is not going to be a significant cost compared to iterating through it.  And it is NOT checking the final character.  Without the sentinel, if the string ends with "bccc", it will not register the set of c's because it's waiting for something to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay to use built-in libraries, you can do this with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Create the groups of tuples with the first item being the character (alphabet) and the second item being the length of the group. Then find the largest length in the `groups` list. Use that to filter the groups result to only those which have that largest length. Since letters may repeat in their max occurrences, make a `set` of them to get a unique letters, which is then sorted in lexicographical order.

```py
import itertools

def longest(seq):
    groups = [(char, len(list(group))) for char, group in itertools.groupby(seq)]
    largest = max(g[1] for g in groups)
    print(largest, ''.join(sorted(set(c for c, l in groups if l == largest))))


longest('bacacccbba')
longest('ccbccbb')
longest('cab')
longest('c')
```

Output:

```
3 c
2 bc
1 abc
1 c
```

Comment: As for the "input format", apart from the number of inputs (sequences), you don't need the length to find the longest seqs. Handle the input separately, and pass each word to the `longest` function.